# Ionic Calendar Date Range

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, date-range, react-daterange-picker

I am a beginner in ReactJS and Ionic. My current project involves developing and integrating a calendar into our mobile app. However, I'm facing an issue with the lack of a built-in calendar date range feature in Ionic. I came across ion2-calendar, but it appears to be compatible only with AngularJS. Can you suggest any alternatives or provide guidance on how I can accomplish this?

[image]